# Prevent page jump on tab click JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a couple of tabs with varying heights. How do I prevent the page from jumping to the top of the container when I click on a tab link?

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/q1tdsar1/1/
Steps to reproduce issue: Click on tab 3, scroll down as if reading the content of tab 3 then click tab 1. **Boom > Page Jump!**

**Here's my JS:**

```
$('#tabs div.tab').hide();
$('#tabs div.tab:first').show();
$('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');

$('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
    $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tabs div.tab').hide();
    $(currentTab).show();
    return false;
});
```

**Here's the HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab">Some content</div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab">Some longer content</div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab">Some even longer content</div>
</div>
```

**Here's CSS:**

```
#tabs ul.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}
#tabs li {
    margin-left: 8px;
    list-style: none;
}
* html #tabs li {
    display: inline;
}
#tabs li,
#tabs li a {
    float: left;
}
#tabs ul li.active {
    border-top:2px #FFFF66 solid;
    background: #FFFFCC;
}
#tabs ul li.active a {
    color: #333333;
}
#tabs div.tab {
    background: #FFFFCC;
    clear: both;
    padding: 15px;
}
#tabs ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: add `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: could you also provide the HTML of the tab with link please?

Comment: @Ales  See updated question

Comment: Why dont you try jquery ui tabs??

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Its gigantic in Kb thats why?! I want to avoid loading in other massive libraries if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use an equal height for all the tabs you have so far. So a script might be helpful, as this is not the page jump that happens, as you already have `return false` in the place of `event.preventDefault();`.

```
TabDivHeight = 0;
$('#tabs div.tab').each(function () {
  $(this).show();
  if ($(this).height() > TabDivHeight)
    TabDivHeight = $(this).height();
  $(this).hide();
});
$('#tabs div.tab').height(TabDivHeight);
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/342fsu8o/**

Or if you would prefer a CSS version, I would say, go for this:

```
#tabs div.tab {
  background: #FFFFCC;
  clear: both;
  padding: 15px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jv3bmtof/**

Or if you prefer a smooth transition, you may use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`:

```
$('#tabs ul li a').click(function () {
    $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tabs div.tab').slideUp();
    $(currentTab).slideDown();
    return false;
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdxyLvLs/**

Comment: This seems to just hide my content and clicking the tabs doesn't work, as in it doesn't reveal the content

Comment: @egr103 **Create a fiddle.** This script must be inserted before you execute the `$('#tabs div.tab').hide();`.

Comment: @egr103 What do you exactly mean by page jumps off?

Comment: @egr103 Yes, I understand. That's the problem I am talking about. It is because of the irregular sizes.

Comment: @egr103 I added my same code in the fiddle. Check now: http://jsfiddle.net/342fsu8o/

Comment: Just noticed your jsFiddle. This isn't variable height. It pushes content underneath it further down that it should if content is less than the max tab height